# Merging JSON files in python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have 2 dicts and I need to combine specific value into a new dict if 1 key ('ID) matches. As they are nested and on different levels, I just can't figure out how, even after playing around a few hours and watching tutorials...

Here are snapshots of the 2 jsons

1st json

```
{
"product": [
    {
        "books": [
            {
                "release": "2017-07-30",
                "status": "H",
                "Title-EN": "EN-TITLE-NAME",
                "Title-DE": "DE-TITLE-NAME",
                "restriction": 1,
                "id": 467541241,
                "onstore": 1
            },
```

2nd json

```
{
"products": [
    {
        "books": [
            {
                "periods": [
                    {
                        "publID": 45547514,
                        "number": 0,
                        "price": {
                            "en": 12,
                            "de": 15
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "id": 467541241
            },
```

I'm trying to get these matched and output like this, basically just adding the two price-key's wherever the ID matches:

```
{
"product": [
{
    "books": [
        {
            "release": "2017-07-30",
            "status": "H",
            "Title-EN": "EN-TITLE-NAME",
            "Title-DE": "DE-TITLE-NAME",
            "restriction": 1,
            "id": 467541241,
            "onstore": 1
            "price-en": 12,
            "price-de": 15,
        },
```

Any hint how I can accomplish this would be great!

Thanks

Comment: Please add what you have tried. The question won't be well-received otherwise because there are so many similar questions

Comment: Loading JSON in to Python just gives you Python lists and dictionaries,  strings and numbers. There is nothing special about JSON here.

Comment: `periods` is a list so it may have multiple values and therefore multiple prices. What then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the following might help. The two nested for loops is to check the id match for each book in your first json with all the books in the second json. At any rate, you should get the idea of how to access nested data in a dictionary from the code below. I am assuming you already have read the jsons  in your python.

```
json_1 = <your first json>
json_2 = <your second json>
for book1 in json_1['product']['books']:
    for book2 in json_2['product']['books']:
        if book1['id'] == book2['id']:
             json_1['product']['books']['price-en'] = book2['periods'][0]['price']['en']
             json_1['product']['books']['price-de'] = book2['periods'][0]['price']['de']
```